# Adjust Datatables column with having a fixed table layout

Tags: html, css

I have a table with a fixed `table layout`. It looks fine except one column because this column doesn't display the data in two lines. Al other columns at least adjust themselves despite of having a fixed table layout. The reason I need to fix this is because this table goes into an iframe.

This is how it looks like.

[image]

Customer email column goes beyond its limit. How can I fix this?

table

```
<table id="esignTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th align="center" class="fieldLabelCell">Line of Business</th>
            <th align="center" class="fieldLabelCell">Insured</th>
            <th align="center" width="15%" class="fieldLabelCell">Customer<br>Phone</th>
            <th align="center" width="16%" class="fieldLabelCell">Policy #</th>
            <th align="center" width="18%" class="fieldLabelCell">E-Sign<br>Created Date</th>
            <th align="center" width="12%" class="fieldLabelCell">Customer<br>Email</th>
            <th align="center" class="fieldLabelCell"># of E-Sign Documents</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> ...
```

Comment: can you simply increase the width?

Comment: I can but it destroys the other columns. Created Date at least shows up in two lines but email doesn't even break in to two lines.

Comment: IT can't break the email address into two lines as there are no spaces to provide a "natural" line break

Comment: yea, because the email is a long string, and the other columns could have the same problem if the word is long.

Comment: I know, I have to adjust this because the table shows up in an iframe and this is the total width of it.

Comment: one solution is to remove table-layout:fixed, will that work for your case?

Comment: If I do that then the table goes beyond the iframe.

Comment: can you use ellipsis or scroll on td? https://jsfiddle.net/4zn4f8dw/

Comment: I can't have it. Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

I found this css trick:

```
overflow-wrap: break-word;
```

from this site:
[CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/)

by [Chris Coyier](https://css-tricks.com/author/chriscoyier/)

This will force a long URL to break.  I have not tried it with what you have, Hope this helps.